# Objective-C runtime information does not match the runtime information required by the test rig

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a couple of old 32-bit, non-ARC, frameworks (pre-compiled, I don't have access to the source) I'm attempting to include in a new project. The project builds fine, but when I attempt to run the unit tests I receive the following error:

> The test bundle at
>   [...]MappingKitTests.octest
>   could not be loaded because its Objective-C runtime information does
>   not match the runtime information required by the test rig.  This is
>   likely because the test rig is being run with Objective-C garbage
>   collection disabled, but the test bundle requires Objective-C garbage
>   collection.  To enable Objective-C garbage collection for the test
>   rig, run it in an environment without the OBJC_DISABLE_GC environment
>   variable.

My new project and unit tests are 32-bit, non-ARC, so this error doesn't make much sense to me.

Do projects and frameworks have to be built with the same version of the OS X SDK? That's the only thing I can think of. The frameworks were built with the 10.6 SDK and my new project is building with the 10.8 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I was getting confused between garbage collection (GC) and automatic reference counting (ARC). This error was referring specifically to GC.

Adding a user-defined build setting of **GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC = unsupported** corrected the issue.

Comment: For me the problem was not GC-related; it arose with my framework which wraps a C++ library. The issue ended up being that the C++ Standard Library the C++ library was built with (using make) did not match both the framework and unit test bundle targets (Xcode). Once I made sure they were all using the same C++ library, the error disappeared.